# Overflow a circle outside the bounds

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to draw objects parallel to the right of the series. Though I am able to do so, but they are getting chopped off. I could append the objects to the svg, but they dont maintain their positions. Need help to fix this. I am not sure how to push the "g".

my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/xzsq4t1z/32/

This is what I am trying in the OnRendered of c3js

```
d3.select('.c3-chart-lines')
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", path.getPointAtLength(len-1).x + 60)
        .attr("cy", path.getPointAtLength(len-1).y)
        .attr("r", "15px")
        .attr("fill", "red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're getting clipped out.

Try removing the clip-path on elements with the c3.chart class:

```
  d3.selectAll(".c3-chart").attr("clip-path", null);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzsq4t1z/70/

This may mean you get other things coming out of the clip bounds too, but I couldn't see anything on a quick look